# can i read and write data to mass storage flash drive by lpc1768 itself alone?

Tags: usb, keil, lpc

i want use lpc1768 to read and write to usb mass storage device
should i use this Fig30?
[Fig30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF3LV.png)
or this Fig29?
[Fig29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuhPt.png)

for reading and writing to USB MASS STORAGE DEVICE?
I'm asking about hardware design of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB Mass storage device is obviously an USB *device* and thus your LPC17xx circuit must supply the +5 volts VBUS line. That is figure 31 in the datasheet.

But that also means you have to implement the difficult USB host in the LPC17xx, and SCSI for mass storage.

You could use figure 30 (OTG) if you needed to connect the lpc17xx itself to host like a PC.

Note that SD cards are *much* simpler to use (via SPI) in Software. And they can be faster: 25 MBit/s instead of 12 MBit/s via USB.